# Windows Metro App <li> tag

Tags: javascript, windows, microsoft-metro, winjs

I am developing a javascript windows store application.

In the displayed html there are some nested `ul` and `li` tags like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="html1.html#anchor">
            <strong>Link1</strong>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="html2.html#anchor">Link2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="html3.html#anchor">Link3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The actual count of the `li` tags is aroung 130, but this is the maximum nesting level.
In the better part of the cases once I try to display this content the application crashes with an access violation exception(no stack trace). If I simply replace all `li` tags with their content however the app runs with no problems.

Any idea what might be causing this since the content is dynamic and I have no control of what tags go in the web page - therefore I can't guarantee it won't happen with other tags?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the issue here. Are you saying your Windows Store app crashes when you attempt to nest 130 lists? [I was able to nest 130 lists](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/83SbE/), and found no issues displaying them. Please share any additional code; perhaps even an example project that crashes.

Comment: need a snippet of html that crashes

Comment: It turns out that the problem isn't in the `li` tags (at least not entirely, since removing them "fixes" the issue) - there are some timeouts that also seem to be part of the crash. I cannot extract a simple HTML code to reproduce the issue since the architecture is quite complex(there is a lot of javascript that could also be causing this). The crash seem to be dependent on the architecture the application is running on - it crashes on the MS Surface tablet(ARM) and a 64-bit Intel processor, but not on 64-bit AMD - running it on an emulator on a 64 AMD showed an error in mshtml.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the problem was related to the [metro's security restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465380.aspx). Apparently somewhere in a function I was calling to process the content some "unsafe" code was executed. I fixed this by wrapping the function like this `MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(myFunction)`. As to why this causes an Access Violation error is beyond me.

I hope this helps anyone struggling with a similar problem since debugging such thing could be a pain.